# How I can insert a URL to all array elements individually in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, hyperlink

```
var countries = ['Afghanistan',"Albania","Algeria"];


var Links=["http://www.google.com","http://www.yahoo.com","http://www.bing.com"];   


/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/

autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
```

How I can pass the above Links array to countries array

Comment: I cannot understand whats your question. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: @HussainAliAkbar   I am referring you a link   https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete  I just want that whenever we press to some country it open a URL

Comment: What's not working? And show us your `autocomplete` implementation please

Comment: he didnt copy that complete code from W3Cschools. he wants to know how to replace 1 array with another one, and thats so simple i don't get what the problem here is, but anyway to change the arrays just use `autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), links);`

Comment: @MatthewHerbst  here is the link I am referring you https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete  I just want that whenever we click on country name it opens a URL along with it

Comment: @Dirk no I don't want to replace array but add links in countries so that when we click on country name than URL should open

Comment: multi dimensional array or json object. and then add javascript to `inp.addEventListener("input" ... ` that creates a link instead of a strong text. your code here is not complete and everyone has to go check the external code to see what you are reffering to or how autocomplete even works in this implementation, thats not how questions here should be asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer would be to refer the code segment below where I create a new array along with urls.

```
var newCountries = countries.map(el => {
  return {
    name: el,
    url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + el
  };
});
```

### Having your own URLs:

If you want to define your own urls for each country, it could done so:

```
var countries = ['Australia', 'Belgium', 'India'];
var urls = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.bing.com', 'http://www.facebook.com']
var newCountries = countries.map((el, idx) => {
  return {
    name: el,
    url: urls[idx]
  }
});
```

**Note:** You can also try the above with the example below, but you will need to ensure you have an array of urls of the same size as countries.

However, here is the an updated version of the example you referred along with the outcome you probably wanted to have:

```js
var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua & Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia & Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central Arfrican Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Curacao","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauro","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","North Korea","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palau","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre & Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Korea","South Sudan","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts & Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad & Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks & Caicos","Tuvalu","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States of America","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Vanuatu","Vatican City","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];

var newCountries = countries.map(el => {
  return {
    name: el,
    url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + el
    };
});
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), newCountries);


function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  var currentFocus;
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}

      currentFocus = -1;
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);

      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        
        if (arr[i].name.substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          b.innerHTML = "<a href=\'" + arr[i].url + "\' target='_blank'><strong>" + arr[i].name.substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>" + arr[i].name.substr(val.length) + "</a>";
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i].name + "'>";
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });

  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        currentFocus++;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        currentFocus--;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { font: 16px Arial; }
a { text-decoration:none; }

.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=text] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
}

.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9; 
}

.autocomplete-active {
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important; 
  color: #ffffff; 
}
```

```html
<h2>Autocomplete</h2>

<p>Start typing:</p>

<form autocomplete="off" action="#">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for code but I want to specify different websites to different countries. Let's say I want to assign India- facebook.com and Afghanistan- google.com how can i do that that but your code is working for wikipedia websites.

Comment: Oh god you are genius in Web development it's working fine but I have a last one questions when I start typing country like Afghanistan the whole text is not linked at all only the written alphabets are labeled with link let's say I write A then only A is linked not full country name. So I need to click on A to open URL     Sorry for asking much questions

Comment: no problem, I've updated the example above. Now the drop-down texts are completely linked, please check it.

Comment: Sorry to irritate you but I swear last question how to make the whole list linked individually let's say if a user pressed on other side of Afghanistan means the right most side where the text is not there so how a URL can also open and just for beautiful view how to hide the underline of countries name because of URL

Answer (score 0):

I made a function that takes two arrays, one of links and one of text, and turns them into links on the page:

```
function addLinks(links, text) {
    for (var x = 0; x < links.length; x++) {
        let newElement = "<a href=" + links[x] + ">" + text[x] + "</a>";
        document.body.append(newElement);
    }
}
```

The arrays must be associative arrays of equal length.